# Android ClassNotFoundException on published app

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I have an application thats been published awhile on Google play, I have been fixing reported bugs as they come in but recently this log below came in and I don't know what to make of it:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mammothtooth.flightinfo/com.mammothtooth.flightinfo.ui.SplashActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mammothtooth.flightinfo.ui.SplashActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/mnt/asec/com.mammothtooth.flightinfo-1/pkg.apk]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1743)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mammothtooth.flightinfo.ui.SplashActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/mnt/asec/com.mammothtooth.flightinfo-1/pkg.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1040)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1735)
```

Does anyone know anything about this type of error log? My SplashScreenActivity is there and its defined as the entry point of the application in the manifest as follows:

```
    <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".ui.SplashActivity" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Would the placing of the uses-library be an issue in the manifest?

I can't reproduce this issue on any of my android devices so any help is greatly appreciated in locating what might be the cause of this issue.

Comment: Does it have something to do with a `MapActivity` perhaps?

Comment: are you sure the activity is in the `ui` package?

Comment: @Siddharth Lele, possibly, I've added more of my manifest, could the placement of the uses-library be an issue on newer Android versions particularly Jelly Bean?

Comment: @Ajmal Salim, Yes it's definitely in the ui package.

Comment: @DonalRafferty: The `uses-library` is in the right place and usually should be the first child element. But I suspected your app does not work on devices without Google Maps installed. That turned out to wrong. It installed and started just fine on my phone.

Comment: @DonalRafferty: See if this works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6736837/450534

Comment: @Siddharth Lel, I'm afraid that is not my issue, now could I see any of the other issues helping in that question. Didn't get device info with the raised bug so I can't easily reproduce the issue either.