# The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. Error

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I get the following error from the emulator in Eclipse when I run an Android application...

"The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again"

There are no error icons appearing in the project folder in Eclipse. I have already tried...

- Cleaning the Project
- Android Tools > Fix Project Properties
- Updating the Build Path
- My Error Log is saying...

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo..."

The Error Log goes onto say...

"Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException..."

Just to note that I do not have a "Build.xml" file in my project folder but instead a "apktool.yml" if this makes any difference.

Any suggestions??

EDIT:

Here's the manifest file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="61" android:versionName="1.2.2" package="com.__.__"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MTActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".RCActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

...

Errors generated LogCat...

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(6220): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(6220): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ir.mtools/com.ir.mtools.MTActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 

com.irtza.pulmtools.MTActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.ir.mtools-1.apk]
 E/AndroidRuntime(6220): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
 E/AndroidRuntime(6220): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
 E/AndroidRuntime(6220): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 E/AndroidRuntime(6220): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
 E/AndroidRuntime(6220): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 E/AndroidRuntime(6220): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 E/AndroidRuntime(6220): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
 E/AndroidRuntime(6220): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(6220): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 E/AndroidRuntime(6220): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
 E/AndroidRuntime(6220): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
 E/AndroidRuntime(6220): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(6220): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ir.mtools.MTActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.ir.mtools-1.apk]
```

Comment: Have you updated your eclipse or SDK lately..If not try what adonal3 has told you check the MF for your activity being declared

Comment: why did you posted only the begining of the error log ?

Comment: I have attached the errors generated from the LogCat

Comment: Is it still the decompiled project from the APK you asked in your deleted question about an hour ago? If so, since you said it's open source, just grab the official source distribution. It should contain working manifest and ant files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android force close: ClassNotFoundException for Activity class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214026/android-force-close-classnotfoundexception-for-activity-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever this happens it means your application has encountered a runtime exception, which means no errors will show up at compile time. In this case I'm guessing you have not declared the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file, but without seeing more code that's only a guess.

Comment: I have attached the AndroidManifest.xml file if it's of any help.

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ir.mtools.MTActivity

Is com.ir.mtools.MTActivity this part of some library? if so have you included it in your build path ?